# How to Format Date in to String Like as "One Days Ago","Minutes Ago" in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, nsdateformatter

I make an Application that contains JSON parse data here is my JSON parse data containing a Date like "2014-12-02 08:00:42" then I convert this Date into following format "12 FEB 2014" like as

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *date=[dict valueForKey:@"post_date"];
NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM YYYY"];
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
cell.timeLabel.text=[dateFormatted uppercaseString];
```

It is working fine but now I want to convert this dateFormatted string into  "One Day Ago","Minutes Ago". I know that this question is asked many times before.

Comment: You need to compare today's date with the JSON result date. On result you can form the string

Comment: @NewStackUser i know that but you can give me Some Material i Example for it.

Answer (score 24):

As of iOS 8, you can get a lot of help (including **localization**) by using **`NSDateComponentsFormatter`**. Note: you can easily change how much granularity the string shows by changing the `allowedUnits` on the components formatter if you want to return a string like "2 days, 3 hours, 5 minutes ago".

**Swift 4:**

```
func timeAgoStringFromDate(date: Date) -> String? {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full

    let now = Date()

    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let components1: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .weekOfMonth, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(components1, from: date, to: now)

    if components.year ?? 0 > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .year
    } else if components.month ?? 0 > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .month
    } else if components.weekOfMonth ?? 0 > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .weekOfMonth
    } else if components.day ?? 0 > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .day
    } else if components.hour ?? 0 > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour]
    } else if components.minute ?? 0 > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .minute
    } else {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .second
    }

    let formatString = NSLocalizedString("%@ left", comment: "Used to say how much time has passed. e.g. '2 hours ago'")

    guard let timeString = formatter.string(for: components) else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(format: formatString, timeString)
}

let str = timeAgoStringFromDate(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-11000))
// Result: "3 hours, 3 minutes left"
```

**Swift:**

```
class func timeAgoStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> NSString? {
    let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .Full

    let now = NSDate()

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Year, .Month, .WeekOfMonth, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second],
        fromDate: date,
        toDate: now,
        options:NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

    if components.year > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .Year
    } else if components.month > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .Month
    } else if components.weekOfMonth > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .WeekOfMonth
    } else if components.day > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .Day
    } else if components.hour > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .Hour
    } else if components.minute > 0 {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .Minute
    } else {
        formatter.allowedUnits = .Second
    }

    let formatString = NSLocalizedString("%@ ago", comment: "Used to say how much time has passed. e.g. '2 hours ago'")

    guard let timeString = formatter.stringFromDateComponents(components) else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(format: formatString, timeString)
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
+ (NSString *)timeAgoStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond)
                                               fromDate:date
                                                 toDate:now
                                                options:0];

    if (components.year > 0) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitYear;
    } else if (components.month > 0) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMonth;
    } else if (components.weekOfMonth > 0) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth;
    } else if (components.day > 0) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    } else if (components.hour > 0) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour;
    } else if (components.minute > 0) {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
    } else {
        formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    }

    NSString *formatString = NSLocalizedString(@"%@ ago", @"Used to say how much time has passed. e.g. '2 hours ago'");

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, [formatter stringFromDateComponents:components]];
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this by using `maximumUnitCount` property and setting it to 1. Then you can set `allowedUnits` to all types you are looking for, then it'll display only the highest unit you have.

Comment: This is perfect, can you update your answer in Objective C with your suggestion?

Comment: Just Perfecto !

Answer (score 16):

On **Swift 5** use the RelativeDateTimeFormatter,

```
let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()

formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(day: -1)) // "1 day ago"
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(hour: 2)) // "in 2 hours"
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(minute: 45)) // "in 45 minutes"
```

set the dateTimeStyle get localized deictic statements e.g. -

```
  formatter.dateTimeStyle = .named 
  formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(day: -1)) // "yesterday"
```

Comment: FYI: Available in iOS 13.0 only

Answer (score 12):

Simplified implementation of @jDutton

**swift4**, **swift3**

```
extension Date {
   var timestampString: String? {
      let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
      formatter.unitsStyle = .full
      formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
      formatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

      guard let timeString = formatter.string(from: self, to: Date()) else {
           return nil
      }

      let formatString = NSLocalizedString("%@ ago", comment: "")
      return String(format: formatString, timeString)
   }
}
```

swift2

```
extension NSDate {
   var timestampString: String? {
      let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
      formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
      formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
      formatter.allowedUnits = [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]

      guard let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(self, toDate: NSDate()) else {
         return nil
      }

      let formatString = NSLocalizedString("%@ ago", comment: "")
      return String(format: formatString, timeString)
   }
}
```

Comment: Error: It gives "4 days, 1 hour ago".  it should be "4 days ago" only.

Comment: @g212gs Looks like this is your issue  http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4939022170324992

Answer (score 8):

I used [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools) to achieve it. It supports Cocoapods installation.

Works like so..

```
NSDate *timeAgoDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-4];
NSLog(@"Time Ago: %@", timeAgoDate.timeAgoSinceNow);
NSLog(@"Time Ago: %@", timeAgoDate.shortTimeAgoSinceNow);

//Output:
//Time Ago: 4 seconds ago
//Time Ago: 4s
```

*taken from the Github page (https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)*

Comment: @lkmal Ezzani Can you Give me Please One Example for it.Here I Use NSDate-Time-Ago then i Get it as Month name Like as "November 19 at 12:37 PM" But i want like as One Month Ago,2Month ago.Please Give me Example for it.

Comment: @AshishGabani, it's best if you go through the Github (link attached above) and try it yourself. You will have better understanding on how it works. Also, you already have the NSDate you want from your `NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];`

Answer (score 7):

This function will return NSString starting from sec to years.
Like if your date is of "1 sec ago" or if it is of "1 min ago" or "1 year ago" and so on.. it will return likewise..

```
+(NSString*)HourCalculation:(NSString*)PostDate

{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *ExpDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:PostDate];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:ExpDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    NSString *time;
    if(components.year!=0)
    {
        if(components.year==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld year",(long)components.year];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld years",(long)components.year];
        }
    }
    else if(components.month!=0)
    {
        if(components.month==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld month",(long)components.month];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld months",(long)components.month];
        }
    }
    else if(components.week!=0)
    {
        if(components.week==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld week",(long)components.week];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld weeks",(long)components.week];
        }
    }
    else if(components.day!=0)
    {
        if(components.day==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld day",(long)components.day];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days",(long)components.day];
        }
    }
    else if(components.hour!=0)
    {
        if(components.hour==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hour",(long)components.hour];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours",(long)components.hour];
        }
    }
    else if(components.minute!=0)
    {
        if(components.minute==1)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld min",(long)components.minute];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld mins",(long)components.minute];
        }
    }
    else if(components.second>=0)
    {
        if(components.second==0)
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 sec"];
        }
        else
        {
            time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld secs",(long)components.second];
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ago",time];
}
```

Comment: @karthikeyan - Where is your edit, about components.week is deprecated?

Comment: @Anand sorry right now i dont have that code.i have edited according to my project.not here!!!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` or `DateComponentFormatter`:

**Swift 3, Xcode version 8.2.1:**

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func date(withFormat format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        dateFormatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}

extension DateComponentsFormatter {
    static let approximatedElapsedTimeFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropAll
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.allowedUnits = [
            .year,
            .month,
            .day,
            .hour,
            .minute
        ]
        // In most cases, this results adding the word "About" at the beginning of the approximation
        formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
        
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension RelativeDateTimeFormatter {
    static let shared: RelativeDateTimeFormatter = {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
        formatter.dateTimeStyle = .named
        formatter.formattingContext = .standalone
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Date {
    var elapsedTime: String? {
        DateComponentsFormatter
            .approximatedElapsedTimeFormatter
            .string(from: self, to: Self.now)
    }
    
    static var now: Date {
        Date()
    }
}

if let date = "2016-11-16 16:28:17".date() {
    if let elapsedTime = date.elapsedTime {
        // Careful with the word "ago". Localize it if your app supports multiple languages.
        let formattedElapsedTime = String(format: "%@ ago", elapsedTime)
        
        // Outputs "About 5 years ago"
        print(formattedElapsedTime)
    }
    
    // Outputs "7 years ago"
    print(RelativeDateTimeFormatter.shared.localizedString(for: date, relativeTo: Date.now))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find also an example here:
https://github.com/tneginareb/Time-Ago-iOS

You can modify the input variable "timeAtMiliseconds", for my example was at the format of date was at Milliseconds.

```
+(NSString *) parseDate: (long)dayago{

if(dayago == 0)
    return @"";

NSString *timeLength =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",dayago];
NSUInteger length = [timeLength length];
if(length == 13){
    dayago = dayago / 1000;

}

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *createdDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dayago];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createdDate];

if([self todaysIsLess:formattedDateString]){
    return @"";
}


NSString *timeLeft;
NSDate *currentDate =[NSDate date];
NSInteger seconds = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:createdDate];




NSInteger days = (int) (floor(seconds / (3600 * 24)));
if(days) seconds -= days * 3600 * 24;

NSInteger hours = (int) (floor(seconds / 3600));
if(hours) seconds -= hours * 3600;

NSInteger minutes = (int) (floor(seconds / 60));
if(minutes) seconds -= minutes * 60;

if(days) {
    timeLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Days", (long)days*-1];
}
else if(hours) { timeLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld H", (long)hours*-1];
}
else if(minutes) { timeLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld M", (long)minutes*-1];
}
else if(seconds)
    timeLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lds", (long)seconds*-1];
//NSLog(@"Days: %lu <>  Hours: %lu <> Minutes: %lu  <> Seconds: %lu",days,hours,minutes,seconds);

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]init];

if (days == 0) {
    if (hours == 0) {
        if (minutes == 0) {
            if (seconds < 0) {
                return @"0s";
            } else {
                if (seconds < 59) {
                    return @"now";
                }
            }
        } else {
            return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lum",minutes];
        }
    } else {
        return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%luh",hours];
    }

} else {
    if (days <= 29) {
        return  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lud",days];
    }
    if (days > 29 && days <= 58) {
        return  @"1Mth";
    }
    if (days > 58 && days <= 87) {
        return  @"2Mth";
    }
    if (days > 87 && days <= 116) {
        return  @"3Mth";
    }
    if (days > 116 && days <= 145) {
        return  @"4Mth";
    }
    if (days > 145 && days <= 174) {
        return  @"5Mth";
    }
    if (days > 174 && days <= 203) {
        return  @"6Mth";
    }
    if (days > 203 && days <= 232) {
        return  @"7Mth";
    }
    if (days > 232 && days <= 261) {
        return  @"8Mth";
    }
    if (days > 261 && days <= 290) {
        return  @"9Mth";
    }
    if (days > 290 && days <= 319) {
        return  @"10Mth";
    }
    if (days > 319 && days <= 348) {
        return  @"11Mth";
    }
    if (days > 348 && days <= 360) {
        return  @"12Mth";
    }

    if (days > 360 && days <= 720) {
        return  @"1Yrs";
    }

    if (days > 720) {

        NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        NSString *fdisplay = [formatter1 stringFromDate:createdDate];
        return fdisplay;
    }

}

return result;
}


-(BOOL) todaysIsLess: (NSString *)dateToCompare{
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateToCompare];
NSComparisonResult result;
result = [today compare:newDate];
if(result==NSOrderedAscending)
    return true;
return false;
}
```

Example how to use it:

```
 long createdDate = 1433183206;//1433183206 --> 01 June 2015
NSLog(@"Parse Date: %@",[self parseDate:createdDate]);
```

Comment: Tried with different inputs and it works great. Thnx

Answer (score 3):

One option is you can compare the current time and previous one and implement switch cases to get the string that you want.

Or you can use any of the following libraries:

1. [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit)
2. [NSDate-Time-Ago](https://github.com/nikilster/NSDate-Time-Ago)

I've created a library for swift, you can get it from here : [Past](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/Past)

Comment: Please You Give me Example for How to Use NSDate-TIme-Ago Library And FormatterKit Library I read In GitHub Documentation but i not Understand Perfectly thanks For Your Compliment.

Comment: Here I Use NSDate-Time-Ago then i Get it as Month name Like as "November 19 at 12:37 PM" But i want like as One Month Ago,2Month ago.Please Give me Example for it

Comment: @AshishGabani: Check the sample app given in FormatterKit, it suites for your need

Comment: Unfortunately, that `NSDate-Time-Ago` only supports English. There is a different `NSDate-Time-Ago` that is now part of DateTools.

Answer (score 1):

```
//String to store the date from json response
   NSString *firstDateString;

 //Dateformatter as per the response date
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// Set the date format according to your needs
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Toronto"]];

//[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm "]  // for 24 hour format
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; // 12 hour format


   firstDateString = value from json;    

 //converting the date to required format.
 NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:firstDateString];
  NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];  

    //Calculating the time interval
    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

    int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;
    int timeResult = ((int)secondsBetween % 86400);
    int hour = timeResult / 3600;
    int hourResult = ((int)timeResult % 3600);
    int minute = hourResult / 60;


    if(numberOfDays > 0)
    {
        if(numberOfDays == 1)
        {
            Nslog("%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",numberOfDays,@"day ago"]);

        }
        else
        {
            Nslog("%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",numberOfDays,@"days ago"]);
        }
    }
    else if(numberOfDays == 0 && hour > 0)
    {
        if(numberOfDays == 0 && hour == 1)
        {
            cell.newsDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",hour,@"hour ago"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.newsDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",hour,NSLocalizedString(@"news_hours_ago",nil)];
        }
    }
    else if(numberOfDays == 0 && hour == 0 && minute > 0)
    {
        if(numberOfDays == 0 && hour == 0 && minute == 1)
        {
            cell.newsDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",minute,@"minute ago"];

        }
        else
        {
            cell.newsDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@",minute,NSLocalizedString(@"news_minutes_ago",nil)];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cell.newsDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"news_seconds_ago",nil)];
    }
```

Comment: could you explain it more?

Comment: what part you can't understand @karthikeyan

Comment: i can understand the code,it would be better for adding comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67110/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-madhu).

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *yourJSONDate;
    if ([[dateFormat stringFromDate:todayDate] integerValue]==[[dateFormat stringFromDate:yourJSONDate] integerValue]) {
        //month is same
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
        if ([[dateFormat stringFromDate:todayDate] integerValue]==[[dateFormat stringFromDate:yourJSONDate] integerValue]) {
        //date is same

        }
        else{
            //date differ
            // now here you can check value for date

        }

    }
    else{
        //month differ
        // now here you can check value for month
    }
```

Try this. Once you get same or differ, you can again check for values and make strings. In if loop you can embed other answers and can make more specific according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
+ (NSString*) getTimestampForDate:(NSDate*)sourceDate {

    // Timezone Offset compensation

    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];

    NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

    NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];

    // Timestamp calculation (based on correction)

    NSCalendar* currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [currentCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:destinationDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSInteger yearDifference = [differenceComponents year];
    NSInteger monthDifference = [differenceComponents month];
    NSInteger dayDifference = [differenceComponents day];
    NSInteger hourDifference = [differenceComponents hour];
    NSInteger minuteDifference = [differenceComponents minute];

    NSString* timestamp;

    if (yearDifference == 0
        && monthDifference == 0
        && dayDifference == 0
        && hourDifference == 0
        && minuteDifference <= 2) {

        //"Just Now"

        timestamp = @"Just Now";

    } else if (yearDifference == 0
               && monthDifference == 0
               && dayDifference == 0
               && hourDifference == 0
               && minuteDifference < 60) {

        //"13 minutes ago"

        timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld minutes ago", (long)minuteDifference];

    } else if (yearDifference == 0
               && monthDifference == 0
               && dayDifference == 0
               && hourDifference == 1) {

        //"1 hour ago" EXACT

        timestamp = @"1 hour ago";

    } else if (yearDifference == 0
               && monthDifference == 0
               && dayDifference == 0
               && hourDifference < 24) {

        timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours ago", (long)hourDifference];

    } else {

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        NSString* strDate, *strDate2 = @"";

        if (yearDifference == 0
            && monthDifference == 0
            && dayDifference == 1) {

            //"Yesterday at 10:23 AM", "Yesterday at 5:08 PM"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yesterday at %@", strDate];

        } else if (yearDifference == 0
                   && monthDifference == 0
                   && dayDifference < 7) {

            //"Tuesday at 7:13 PM"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", strDate, strDate2];

        } else if (yearDifference == 0) {

            //"July 4 at 7:36 AM"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", strDate, strDate2];

        } else {

            //"March 24 2010 at 4:50 AM"

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
            strDate = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            strDate2 = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];

            timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ at %@", strDate, strDate2];
        }
    }

    return timestamp;
}
```

**NOTE:** The first few lines are there for timezone offset correction. If it is not needed, comment it out, and use the `sourceDate` wherever `destinationDate` is used.

Answer (score 0):

> Whatsapp conversation list kind of date formating....

```
-(NSString *)getChatListFormatDate{

    NSString *differencDate = @"";

    NSDate *lastSeenDate = self;
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSString *timeDateStr = [self getStringFromDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *dayOfWeekString = [lastSeenDate getStringFromDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

    NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *calendarLastSeen = [calendar components:units fromDate:lastSeenDate];
    NSDateComponents *calendarToday = [calendar components:units fromDate:currentDate];

    BOOL isThisYear = calendarLastSeen.year == calendarToday.year;
    BOOL isThisMonth = calendarLastSeen.month == calendarToday.month;
    BOOL isThisWeekOfMonth = calendarLastSeen.weekOfMonth == calendarToday.weekOfMonth;

    NSInteger dayDiff = calendarToday.day - calendarLastSeen.day;

    if (isThisYear && isThisMonth && dayDiff == 0) {
        differencDate = timeDateStr;//Today
    }
    else if (isThisYear && isThisMonth && dayDiff == 1){
        differencDate = @"Yesterday";
    }
    else if (isThisYear && isThisMonth && isThisWeekOfMonth){
        differencDate = dayOfWeekString;//apply Date
    }
    else {
        NSString *strDate = [self getStringFromDateFormat:@"d/MM/yy"];
        differencDate = strDate;
    }
    return differencDate;
}
```